# Separating Identity tables' and business tables' DbContexts while sharing foreign key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using IdentityServer as an Authorization Server for my API. It is a separate ASP.NET Core Identity + IdentityServer4 project that handles user login/login/register/etc. My 'buisness' API is in a separate ASP.NET Core Web API project.

I am using Entity Framework Core code-first migrations to generate my database tables for both these projects.

The Auth Server project has all the default Identity user tables within its `ApplicationDbContext` (the default Identity DbContext), as you'd expect.

The buisness API Server, however, need to have its own tables. Most of these tables will need to have a `UserId` foreign key (eg. in a todo app, the API would have the todo items table where users and todo items have a one-to-many FK relationship). This means the API Server has it's own DbContexts that I've defined, with most of the DbSets having foreign key relations to users (`ApplicationUser`).

How would I set that up? EF Core doesn't seem to support FK relations across multiple DbContexts. Also, doing that, you'd have to inject the context classes twice (once per project) which requires duplicating my connection string. I know I can just let my Auth Server project also handle my business tables (as easy as adding more DbSets) but I'd like to keep them separate. Is there a clean, idiomatic way of doing this or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do this is to add a User table to the Business DbContext that has a row inserted when a user is registered in the Identity DbContext. That User row has a reference to the Id created in the Indentity DbContext but is usable as a foreign key because it is in the same DbContext with the other tables in the Business DbContext.